# setting a listview from sql with json

Tags: android, sql, json, listview, android-arrayadapter

iv been having trouble trying to set a listview from a json object from mySQL, iv given internet permission i have working item_list files, so here is my code to check out

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String result = "";
InputStream is = null;
String storyNames = "";
//String[] STORYLIST = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_list);        

    returnJson();
    String[] STORYLIST = new Gson().fromJson(result,String[].class);

    setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, STORYLIST));

    ListView menulist = getListView();
    menulist.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    menulist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {    
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {      

            if  (position == 0) {
            //  Intent buttona = new Intent(view.getContext(), OneActivity.class);
              //  startActivity(buttona);
            }

            if (position == 1) {
             //   Intent buttonb = new Intent(view.getContext(), TwoActivity.class);
             //   startActivity(buttonb);
            }

            if (position == 2) {
               // Intent buttonc = new Intent(view.getContext(), ThreeActivity.class);
               // startActivity(buttonc);
            }

            if (position == 3) {
                //Intent buttond = new Intent(view.getContext(), FourActivity.class);
                //startActivity(buttond);
            }

        }

});


    //end of oncreate()    
}

public void returnJson(){

    //TextView one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    try{
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/textures_story_list.php");

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e) {
    //  one.setText("error3");
    }

    try{


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"), 8);                      
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

    }catch(Exception e) {
    //  one.setText("error2");          
        }

    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        String storyNames = "";
        for(int i = 0;i<jArray.length();i++){
               // storyNames += jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("story_name") + "\n"; 

        }
    //  one.setText(storyNames);

    }
    catch(JSONException e) {
    //  one.setText("error1");

    }
        return;


//end of returnJson()   
}

//end of class body    
}
```

i think the problem is with 
    setListAdapter
or 
    String[] STORYLIST

can someone please help with whats going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is wrong for you. But this bit of code works very well for me. Its something I put together from a few tutorials.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getItems());
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private List<String> getItems() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("whatever", "xxxx"));
    JSONArray jArray = connectToServer("http://10.0.2.2/textures_story_list.php", pairs);
    JSONObject json_data = null;
    for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            list.add(json_data.getString("name"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return list;
}

public static JSONArray connectToServer(String address, List<NameValuePair> valuePairs) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(address);
    try {           
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(valuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF8"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line="0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        String result = sb.toString();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
        return array;
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}   
}
```